# Should I use a Java Regex Pattern or simple System Format?

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently trying to to set up a program so the user must enter a specific string of characters for example `DeskID` followed by 2-3 ints, thus: `DeskNO10` or `DeskNO42`

At the moment, I have tried:

```
if(Pattern.matches("[DeskNO0-9]",desk)) {
    System.out.println("Accepted");
} else {
    System.out.println("Rejected");
}
```

This doesn't work - is there any suggestions I could make it work or would it be advisable, if I just use a simple `println` statement using `%s` and `%2d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
if(Pattern.matches("DeskNO[0-9]{2,3}",desk))
```

the `[DeskNO0-9]` is a character class, so it match only one character from within brackets like `D`, `e`, `9`, etc., this is why it doesn't work.

With `DeskNO[0-9]{2,3}` the `DeskNO` is an obligatory part, and `[0-9]{2,3}` means it should be followed with two or three digits.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
if (desk.matches("DeskNO\\d{2,3}")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex uses a *character class*, i.e. the thing enclosed in square brackets. This means that the expression would accept any *single* character defined in the square brackets, i.e. `D`, `e`, `s`, `k`, `N`, `O`, `0`, `1`, ..., `9`. This is certainly *not* what you want.

The correct regex would be

```
"DeskNO\\d{2,3}"
```

However, the choice of the approach is up to you: regex may be too much for the job that simple. You could test if the string `startsWith("DeskNO")`, then take the suffix with `substring(6)`, and check if it's two or three digits.